# Using limits to prove inequalities

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality

Basically my question is that if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)>\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ does that mean $f(x)>g(x)$ for an $x$ assuming that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both always positive and increasing.

So in terms of proving what I've done is I've shown that $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x)>\lim_{x \to 2} g(x)$ is true so therefore the inequality is true for $x\geq2$. I know that another commenter used sin and cos to disprove that but I'm assuming that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are always positive and increasing. For the domain of f and g, it would just be $x\geq0$.

Comment: If $\lim f(x)>\lim g(x)$ then $f(x)>g(x)$ for all big enough $x$.

Comment: Yes, if you know the rigorous definitions of limits, you can prove it quite easily.

Comment: @zugzug I'm not sure what the rigorous definitions are. Is there anyway you could help me with the proof? Based on what Jakobian mentioned, I've been trying to show that if the inequality holds for lim→2()>lim→2() then it'll hold for any x>=2.

Comment: @fjafadfa Take $f(x)=\sin(\frac{x\pi}{4})$ and $g(x)=\cos(\frac{x\pi}{4})$ . Then limit of f is greater than that of g at $2$. But $f>g$ cannot hold  $\forall x\geq2$

Comment: I have an answer, but I can't post it since this is an isolated question. Please edit it and mention what you tried. Also, mention whether anything is said about the domain of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: @SayanDutta I've made the edit.

Comment: @fjafadfa Done answering

Comment: It's unclear if you are asking 1) Is it always true that $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$?  The answer to that is NO.  Or are you asking 2) must there always exist some $x$ somewhere where $f(x) > g(x)$?  The answer to that is YES.... by the way if $\lim_{x\to 2} f(x) > \lim_{x\to 2} g(x)$ does not at *all* imply that $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x \ge 2$.  I really don't know why you would think that.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asked with $\color{red}{\text{an}}$ $x$. Here's the proof of that-

Assuming that the limits of $f$ and $g$ exists, let us assume that
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=F$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=G$$

Now, it is given that $F>G$.

Take $\epsilon=\frac{F-G}4$

For this epsilon, there must be an $N_f$ and and $N_g$ such that
$$F-\epsilon<f(N_f)<F+\epsilon$$
and
$$G-\epsilon<g(N_g)<G+\epsilon$$
because of the definition of limits.

Now, take the maximum of $N_f$ and $N_g$ to be $N$. Since $f$ and $g$ are increasing, we must have
$$F-\epsilon<f(N)<F+\epsilon$$
and
$$G-\epsilon<g(N)<G+\epsilon$$

In particular,
$$F-\epsilon<f(N)$$
and
$$g(N)<G+\epsilon$$

So,
$$f(N)>g(N)$$

This completes the proof.

---

However, the OP writes in the comments that it was a typo and the actual question deals with $\color{red}{\text{any}}$ $x$.

This statement is not true and a counterexample can easily be constructed using the idea of a [Sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). The counterexample I am giving assumes that the domain of $f$ and $g$ are $\mathbb R$. The same idea can be used to construct functions on any other domain.

Take
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$
and
$$g(x)=\frac{0.5}{1+e^{-x}}+0.1$$
Note that
$$1=\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)>\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=0.6$$
but
$$0.1192\approx f(-2)<g(-2)\approx 0.1596$$

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I understand how you got f(N)>g(N) but I'm a bit confused as to why maximizing  and  to N shows that the inequality holds for any value. Doesn't that mean the inequality only holds in the domain −<()<+ ?

Comment: @fjafadfa You wrote in your question that $f(x)>g(x)$ for $\color{red}{\text{an}}$ $x$ and not $\color{red}{\text{any}}$ $x$. If the actual question is $\color{red}{\text{any}}$ $x$, then it's not even true. It's very easy to construct counterexamples.

Comment: That's a typo on my part. My bad.

Comment: @fjafadfa Please check the edit.

Comment: @fjafadfa Do you understand the difference "any" vs. "an" makes?  You claim it was a typo (implying you meant "any" all along) but then you editted your question and did *not* change "an" to "any" and still commented about comments based on the "an" interpretation.